# Where does Django store the project path?

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

I want to rename a project which I created with:

```
django-admin.py startproject
```

But after renaming the folder and all the references inside my project, I still can't get it to start. It says myproject.settings is not in the pythonpath. Since the old project name is neither in the pythonpath i figure that django must keep these names and paths somewhere else. Where does it store this information ?

I know I could just add the path to sys.path while execution, but i want to fix this completely.

If i run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

The name for 'mysite' is already the correct one and corrosponds with the folder name. But still it can't find it.

Any ideas?

PS: I'm running debian.

Comment: Can you show the exact traceback you get?

Comment: besides the traceback, can you pastebin your settings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm sorry, but the solution was more simple in my case:

one of the apps had the same name i wanted to give to the project. this resulted in the described error message !

sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't store the project path anywhere. Everything is calculated relative to the path you specified for the settings module.

If you renamed your project folder and it's still trying to load the old settings, it's possible that you still have the old settings file configured somewhere, e.g. in the environment `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is still pointing to `oldproject.settings` or your WSGI server is still configured to load `oldproject.settings`. Also check that you don't have any package weirdness in your interpreter's `site-packages`.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. i'm still trying to get the developement server to work (python manage.py runserver) which tells me it cant find mysite.settings, because it's not in the search path. so why isn't it in the python path if it generates it on it's own ? by itself it found the right new name mysite.settings instead of oldsite.settings, but it just cant't find it. so i guess it must store location information somehow !?

Comment: Generally, `manage.py` tries to load the settings module from the current package, unless you set an environment variable or provide the `--settings` option. Can you check if it was modified and can you set `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and review `os.environ` and `os.path`? Seems like we'll have to dig deeper to debug this.